# Node js: How to handler multiple request in one API

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Let say this is my API:

```
app.post('/refund', function (req, res) {
        Transaction.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body.transaction_id}, {$set: {refund_status: true}}).
        exec(function (err, transaction_status) {
            res.end("Refund successfully")
        }
}
```

If two admins click the refund button at the same time. My customer will receive a double refund.

So, how to prevent these issues?

Comment: That can be achieved in many ways, too many to be placed in one answer, so please put more details and focus in your question.

Comment: You may try with https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html

Answer (score 1):

Simply get the transaction first and check the refund status and update. If its false refund. If its true tell its already refunded.

```
  app.post('/refund', function (req, res) {
    // get the transaction first
    Transaction.find({_id: req.body.transaction_id}, function(err, doc) {
      if (doc.refund_status == false) {
         Transaction.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body.transaction_id}, {$set: {refund_status: true}}).exec(function(err, transaction_status) {
           res.end("Refund successfully")
      })
      } else { // already refunded
        res.end("Already refunded")
      }
     })
  }
```

Comment: If the admin clicks the refund button at the same time. I don't this will work right

Comment: Even if that happens the 2 request will be queued in the server. Meaning one will run first other later.

Comment: @Erenn yea but the Transaction lookup is async, so it might fetch the doc after the new request is being processed, which might lead to the refund occurring twice

Answer (score 0):

Implement your refund logic in a callback from [session.withTransaction()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions/). That will prevent concurrent updates. Don't worry about the async stuff; .withTransaction() handles it correctly.

Or, make your refund logic [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Computer_science_meaning). That is, implement it in a way that calling it multiple times does exactly the same thing as calling it once. Your setup is almost idempotent as it is: you start with the transaction id and set its refund statuse to true. But the idempotence may not work for you if you must report when the transaction is already refunded.